# Basic C++ Function Pointers & Struct

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, struct

I'm having issues passing an array struct into a function for processing.

I think I need to pass the function the address of the array, however have got multiple compiler errors and am running out of combinations to try.

The function then needs to return a value to a new struct member.

Here is my best shot!

```
  //-----------------

  void Function(struct MyStruct* ptr);

  //------------------

  int main(){

  MyStruct array[MAX];

for (int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
{

    File>>array[i].V1;
    File>>array[i].V2;
    File>>array[i].V3;
    File>>array[i].V4;
    MyStruct* ptr = &array[i];
    array[i].V5 = Function(ptr);
}
  }

  //-----------------------

  void Function(struct MyStruct* ptr)
  {
  // do something with the struct, how to I access each element in here?
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your `main` looks good. Don't forget to give `Function` a useful return type that'll match `array[i].V5`, and inside it you may access the members of `MyStruct` through the pointer like `ptr->V1`, `ptr->V2` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `void` type for `Function`, which is why you can't return anything. You should make it return whatever `V5`'s type is instead.

Also, to access a element of `ptr`, use the arrow notation:

```
ptr->V5
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Within my function: ptr->V5 = 1.0; gives error C2227: left of '->V5' must point to class/struct/union/generic type. This would save me having to define return types, which is what I want to do. Thanks!

Comment: @user1055774 How are you defining `MyStruct`? You should update your question to feature your full code.

Comment: Sorry, that's me. I had assigned a value that was of an incorrect type. The code is now working, sometimes you just need someone to point out the obvious. Thanks!